# Batch CMR - Delete first two lines, add text on bottom line and change extension

Tags: batch-file, rename, edit

Wondering if you guys could help with what should be easy if you have a little knowledge on programming.

All I have to do is delete the first two lines of a text file, add `unit= mm` at the end and change the extension from .txt to .tfm to a batch of files.

Ex: I would have a bunch of .txt files that look like this:

```
VERSION =   1
MATRIX  =
-8.53018635e-001   5.21877542e-001  -1.74356374e-003   1.16403895e+004
-4.70640528e-001  -7.70705865e-001  -4.29546229e-001   2.25759988e+004
-2.25514305e-001  -3.65590346e-001   9.03043187e-001  -3.03304760e+004
 0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000   1.00000000e+000
```

And my output should be:

```
-9.23773447e-001   3.82937087e-001  -1.34365271e-003   1.57083071e+004
-3.45348709e-001  -8.34603411e-001  -4.29151971e-001   1.99811620e+004
-1.65459623e-001  -3.95975167e-001   9.03231299e-001  -3.39194884e+004
 0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000   1.00000000e+000
unit= mm
```

And then having the extension changed from .txt to .tfm.

So basically it is always a consistent 6 lines file that has to have the first two lines removed and then add a 5th line with "units= mm" at the end.
Also the file can be overwritten.

Hope someone can help me with this one.

Answer (score 0):

if all the text files are in the same directory(not tested):

```
@echo off
::change the dir location
set "dir_with_files=c:\somedir"

pushd "%dir_with_files%"
for %%# in (*.txt) do (
  break>"%%~n#.tfm"
  for "usebackq skip=2 tokens=* delims=" %%$ in ("%%~f#") do (
     (echo(%%$)>>"%%~n#.tfm" 
  )
  (echo(unit= mm)>>"%%~n#.tfm" 
)
:: check if the new files are ok and delete the echo to activate deletion
del /q /f *.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%i in (*.txt) do (
    more +2 "%%i">"%%~ni.tfm"
    echo units=mm>>"%%~ni.tfm"
    REM del "%%i"
)
```

reference: `more /?`, `for /?`

Comment: The second `echo` will overwrite the file, use `>>`. Also, not sure about the `.tfm` file format requirements, but note that `more` command will replace tabs with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for you help guys.
At the end I used:

```
for %%i in (*.txt) do (
    more +2 "%%i">>"%%~ni.tfm"
    echo units=mm>>"%%~ni.tfm"
    REM del %%i
)
del *.txt
```

It did the trick.

All the best and thanks again.